# the mystery of lesscss

Tags: html, css, less

Hi I am trying to work out if it is worth using LESSCSS.

After much research and playing I see that it is not supported by older browsers and needs to be compiled before it is used. Is it even worth using? I know that it makes css easier write, but is it even worth it if what you are writing is not what will be on live when it  is used?

Thanks

Comment: That is not correct "and needs to be compiled before it is used" and it definitely worth it

Comment: thanks for the reply can you please help me by saying why?  thanks

Comment: 1. you don't have to compile it, you can include the less file as a css file and a JS which will compile it run time. 2. it is really easy to use create complex css hierarchies and color schemas with less. These 2 things make it quite easy to create modular css without redundant code parts  (this is why I use it)

Comment: I would check out codekit and sass. Compiling gives you the ability to see your designs come to life as you make changes on your local server. It rules. I use transmit 4 to mount remote disks. It's cool that the server can deal with preprocessors, but then you have to upload and refresh - it's well worth 40 bucks and its a pleasure to work with. Partials and variable are an easy way to get started and they change everything. Have fun!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, there are two ways of using LESSCSS :

- Client-side : the `.less` file is sent to client and is executed by the browser, uses javascript and requires recent browser.
- Server-side : the `.less` files are compiled to plain `.css` files, which are sent to the client.

The second one requires more configuration of the server, but requires nothing more than CSS compatibility from the client.

You can find more details on the LESSCSS main page, at the bottom of "usage" section : [here](http://lesscss.org/#usage).

Comment: thanks for the reply  - so am I correct in saying that its best to use the version that compiles on the server  - eg  http://leafo.net/lessphp/   or   http://www.dotlesscss.org/  for when I use c#  or php?  thanks

Comment: @Hello-World `less` comes with a command-line compiler : `lessc`. Your tools are useful if your less scripts are to be dynamically generated. If your design doesn't change a lot, it's lighter modifying the `less` files and compiling them manually with `lessc myless.less mycss.css` then including css file in your HTML documents, raher than dynamically compiling them at each request.